# Analysis and plotting from a data file (.dat) with n sets of x and y values in python

Tags: python, arrays, plot, analysis

I've been trying to analyse data from a .dat file.  The experiment in the file repeats (very many) times, such that each experiment has n data points for each of the r experiments. As an example: r = 4 experiments, with n = 3 data points in each experiment:

```
    1     4.8
    2     3.4
    3     2.3

    1     6.5
    2     5.3
    3     4.2

    1     9.8
    2     8.4
    3     7.6

    1     13.8
    2     12.4
    3     11.6
```

I want to read the file and plot 4 graphs - the first 3, second 3 and third 3 and fourth 3 rows.  My code so far is this:

```
    for line in myfile:
        if not line.strip():#takes out empty rows
            continue
        else:
            data.append(line)

    for line in data:
        x, y = line.split()
        timestep.append(float(x))
        value.append(float(y))

    z = 0.0
    j = 1 
    n = 3 #no. of data points in one experiment
    r = 4 #no. of times experiment repeats
    x = np.arange(1,n)

    for k in range(1, r):
        for i in (value):
            j += 1     
            if n%j != 0: #trying to break the loop after the first experiment of n data points
                z = i
                y_"str(j)" = [] #I want to call this array y_j, i.e. y_1 for the first loop or y_2 for the second, etc, wild index in python?! :( 
                y_"str(j)".append(z)

        else:
            value = value[steps:] #trying to remove the first three points before starting to for loop again
        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(x, y_str(j),'r', label = "y_str(j)")
        plt.title('y ' +str(j) )
        plt.show()
```

I'll be analysing it more, but I'm just having difficulty in performing the same analysis (plotting, etc) every n times in the big array of data.  It might not even be necessary to split my 2 column input data into separate x and y columns, but I was getting annoying int and float errors using data[i][2] in the for loop.

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read in the data by experiment, using the empty line as separator:

```
data = []
exp = [[], []]
for line in myfile:
    if line.strip():
        for index, value in enumerate(line.split()):
            exp[index].append(float(value))
    else:
        data.append(exp)
        exp = [[], []]
```

and plot them all in one plot:

```
for number, exp in enumerate(data, 1):
    plt.plot(*exp, label='experiment {}'.format(number))
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.title('My Experiments')
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try do something like this:

```
for line in myfile:
    if line.strip():#takes out empty rows
        x, y = line.split()
        timestep.append(float(x))
        value.append(float(y))

n = 3 #no. of data points in one experiment
r = 4 #no. of times experiment repeats
x = np.arange(1, n+1) # you don't need to use it. just plot(y)
colors = ['r', 'b', 'g', 'k'] 
for k in range(r):
    y = value[k*n:(k+1)*n]

    # plt.subplot(r+1, 1, k+1) #if you want place it on different plots
    plt.plot(x, y, colors[k], label="%d experiment" % (k+1))

plt.legend(loc=1) # or wherever you want
plt.title('Experiments')
plt.show()
```